# In the category Set, why does there need to exist a morphism from a set to a singleton set?

Tags: category-theory

This question of mine arises from my reading of the quite-helpful-for-me, posted answers to the question:

[In the Set category, why is every singleton a terminal object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820582/in-the-set-category-why-is-every-singleton-a-terminal-object)
Especially helpful for me was the answer posted by @Lærne :
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2820583

But I have a gap in my understanding. I know that the  category is the category whose objects are sets, and whose morphisms from some set A to some set B are the functions from A to B. I know that in general, in a category, there is no requirement for there to be a morphism from an object to another distinct object. I understand why, if there does indeed exist a function from an object (set) A to a singleton set, then that function is unique. But I don't understand why, in the first place, a function needs to exist from an object (set) A to a singleton set.

Comment: $B=\{b\}$: $f(a)=b$.

Comment: Note that in the category $\sf Set$, the arrows between any two objects are *all* the functions between them. So, your question is then just amounting to showing that there does exist a function from any set to any singleton set.

Comment: You have to know what the definition of a function is. A function $A \rightarrow B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ so that some requirements are fulfilled. Then if $B$ is a singleton it turns out that the set $A \times B$ as a subset of itself satisfies these conditions for a function. This is also the only subset of $A \times B$ so that the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 6):

If $\{x\}$ is a Singleton set, then the constant function which ignores its input and outputs $x$ is a function from $A \to \{x\}$ for any set $A$. Moreover, this function is unique since $x$ is the *only* choice of output.

---

I hope this helps ^_^