# Why, in a set category, are all possibly functions included?

Tags: category-theory

I read in [this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740345/in-the-category-set-why-does-there-need-to-exist-a-morphism-from-a-set-to-a-sin) that the reason, in set category theory, singletons have morphisms from all other objects is that all possible functions are included. Why are all possible functions included? Couldn't we have just two singleton sets and no other sets, with each singleton having an endomorphism and there being no other morphisms? Wouldn't that satisfy the axioms of category theory?

Comment: What do you mean by “a set category”? In the question you linked, the discussion was about a specific category - the category of sets.

Comment: What is "a set category"? There is the notion of "concrete category" (objects are sets, arrows are functions between the sets), and we do nt require "all functions" (E.g., the category of groups). Then there is $\mathsf{Set}$, which by definition is the category whose objects are all sets, and arrows are all set-theoretic functions.

Comment: Yeah what I mean was a category of sets, sorry. As a beginner in the topic, I have not mastered to vocabulary. From @arturo remarks, it appears that when the say that all singletons are terminal objects, they must be referring to "Set." It appears that I have no appreciation of when people are talking about concrete categories, on the one hand, and "Set" on the other.

Comment: I'm pretty curious about the category Set; is there only one such category (I realize this question may be ambiguous)? Does it include, as its objects, sets whose elements are sets containing other sets, for example? Why is this category important? It appears to be related to functional programming.

Comment: Note that the post says "In the category Set"; so 'Set' is the name of the category and this name is usually understood to mean "objects are all sets, arrows are all set-theoretic functions" (just like when we say "the category Group" we mean the category whose objects are all groups, and whose arrows are group morphisms). As to your final query, provided you *define* the unique endomorphism as the identity arrow of the corresponding object (or you take the actual identity function), with corresponding composition rules, yes, that's a category.

Comment: The category $\mathsf{Set}$ by definition has "all" sets as objects, and the arrows between object $X$ and object $Y$ are by definition all functions from the set $X$ to the set $Y$. The identity arrows are the identity functions, and arrow compositions is the composition of functions. "All sets" here means all sets within a particular model of Set Theory, so for example if you think of ZFC as "Set Theory", then every set consists just of sets, no urelements. As to "Why is this category important?", because it models set theory within category theory.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely consider categories as you suggest. From the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of all the sets and all the functions between them, you can extract smaller [subcategories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcategory).

For example:

- The category of sets and injections,
- The category of sets and bijections,
- The category of finite sets and functions,

or, as you suggest:

- The category consisting of a singleton {a}, a singleton {b} and the two functions $$id_{\{a\}}:\{a\} \rightarrow \{a\}$$ $$id_{\{b\}}:\{b\} \rightarrow \{b\}$$

This last category perfectly verifies the axioms that should be verified by a category. This is what we call a [discrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_category) ie. a category with only the identities as morphisms and no morphisms between different objects. And this is true that in a discrete category with at least two objects, you can't have a [terminal object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects).